# How to use Content-Encoding: gzip with Python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, gzip, simplehttpserver

I'm using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to serve up a directory for local testing in a web browser. Some of the content includes large data files. I would like to be able to gzip them and have SimpleHTTPServer serve them with Content-Encoding: gzip.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 16):

*This is an old question, but it still ranks #1 in Google for me, so I suppose a proper answer might be of use to someone beside me.*

The solution turns out to be very simple. in the do_GET(), do_POST, etc, you only need to add the following:

```
content = self.gzipencode(strcontent)
...your other headers, etc...
self.send_header("Content-length", str(len(str(content))))
self.send_header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(content)
self.wfile.flush()
```

strcontent being your actual content (as in HTML, javascript or other HTML resources)
and the gzipencode:

```
def gzipencode(self, content):
    import StringIO
    import gzip
    out = StringIO.StringIO()
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode='w', compresslevel=5)
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
    return out.getvalue()
```

Comment: Of course, the above were straight copy-pastes of that code. But then again, the above snippets say it all and the complete functioning code also serves as a JSON bridge which would kinda blur the purpouse of this question. Anyway, drop me a mail if you need more info or the code.

Answer (score 9):

Since this was the top google result I figured I would post my simple modification to the script that got gzip to work.

https://github.com/ksmith97/GzipSimpleHTTPServer

Answer (score 5):

As so many others, I've been using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for local testing as well. This is still the top result on google and while https://github.com/ksmith97/GzipSimpleHTTPServer is a nice solution, it enforces gzip even if not requested and there's no flag to enable/disable it.

I decided to write a tiny cli tool that supports this. It's go, so the regular install procedure is simply:

`go get github.com/rhardih/serve`

If you already have `$GOPATH` added to `$PATH`, that's all you need. Now you have `serve` as a command.

https://github.com/rhardih/serve

Answer (score 3):

This was a feature request but rejected due to wanting to keep the simple http server simple: https://bugs.python.org/issue30576

The issue author eventually released a standalone version for Python 3: https://github.com/PierreQuentel/httpcompressionserver

Comment: Just a heads up for others. httpcompressionserver did not automatically bind the address the same way as "http.server". For me it crashed.
I had to start it with: python3 -m httpcompressionserver --bind 0.0.0.0
See: https://github.com/PierreQuentel/httpcompressionserver/issues/2

Comment: That should've been fixed on pypi. Contact the author if it hasn't.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @velis answer above, here is how I do it.  gZipping small data is not worth the time and can increase its size.  Tested with Dalvik client.

```
def do_GET(self):
    ... get content
    self.send_response(returnCode)       # 200, 401, etc
    ...your other headers, etc...
    if len(content) > 100:                       # don't bother compressing small data
        if 'accept-encoding' in self.headers:    # case insensitive
            if 'gzip' in self.headers['accept-encoding']:
                content = gzipencode(content)    # gzipencode defined above in @velis answer
                self.send_header('content-encoding', 'gzip')
    self.send_header('content-length', len(content))
    self.end_headers()          # send a blank line
    self.wfile.write(content)
```

Answer (score -1):

From looking at SimpleHTTPServer's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html), there is no way. However, I recommend [lighttpd with the mod_compress module](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-mod_compress-gzip-compression-tutorial.html).